# php как сделать так, чтобы функция возвращала значение, а не сразу выводила его?

Tags: php, функции

Всем привет. Подскажите пожалуйста. Есть функция:

```
function foo() {echo "Слово";}
```

Как вывести значение функции в нижнем регистре? Что то типа такого:

```
$str = mb_strtolower(foo());        
echo $str;
```

Чтобы получилось:

```
слово
```

Answer (score 1):

Функция:

```
function foo() {
    return "Слово";
}
```

Вывод на экран:

```
$str = mb_strtolower(foo());
echo  $str;
```

Answer (score 0):

В вашем примере значение функции лучше возвращать через return, и перед возвратом применить mb_strtolower():

```
function foo() {return mb_strtolower("Слово");}
```

и дальше использовать в коде:

```
echo foo(); // что бы вывести на экран
```

или:

```
$str = foo(); // что бы присвоить значение переменной
```

Comment: Спасибо, так работает.